# Not getting an oid in response to login?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the followung URL to try and login to my azure ad b2c account:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_B2CSignIn&client_id={client_id}&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope=openid offline_access&response_type=code+id_token&prompt=login
```

When I run it I get an id_token in the response, when I convert that to a json file I noticed there's no oid value. This is on a new azure ad b2c directory, I have an older one which gives me the oid in the response so I must be missing a setting somewhere but haven't been able to find it.

Comment: In the "Application claims" settings for the built-in policy, did you select the "User's Object ID" claim?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett good catch, I added user's object id but surprisingly that didn't fix the issue...

Comment: ah weirdly enough it just started working (from your first suggestion), not sure why it took a while could be a propagation issue? Either way feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: Policies are cached so it can be a few minutes before you observe the latest settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding the built-in policy, in the "Select application claims" panel, you must select the "User's Object ID" claim.

[image]

By default, the object identifier for a signed-in user is issued as both the `sub` (subject) and `oid` (object identifier) claims in the identity token, as follows:

```
{
  "exp": 1520933155,
  "nbf": 1520929555,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0/",
  "sub": "{userObjectId}",
  "aud": "{applicationClientId}",
  "nonce": "defaultNonce",
  "iat": 1520929555,
  "auth_time": 1520929555,
  "oid": "{userObjectId}",
  "tfp": "{policyName}"
}
```